# Do not create everytime valueEventListener

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

How i can optimize my code? 
In every function i created `valueEventListener`.

Here is all code:

```
class TargetsPresenter(private val contract: SelectTargetViewContract) {

    var firebaseUser: FirebaseUser? = null
    var targetList: ArrayList<Goal> = ArrayList()
    private var databaseReference: DatabaseReference? = null
    private var targetsRef: DatabaseReference? = null
    private var uid: String? = null

    fun setInitialData() {
        firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser
        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
        uid = firebaseUser?.uid
        targetsRef = databaseReference?.child("targets")
            ?.child("users")?.child(uid.toString())
            ?.child("targets")
    }

    fun getTargetsFromDb() {
        val valueEventListener = object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                targetList.clear()
                dataSnapshot.children
                    .mapNotNull { it.getValue(Goal::class.java) }
                    .toCollection(targetList)
                contract.updateViewContent()
            }

            override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {
                Log.d("some", "Error trying to get targets for ${databaseError.message}")
            }
        }
        targetsRef?.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener)
    }

    fun getTargetsByPriority() {
        val valueEventListener = object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                targetList.clear()
                dataSnapshot.children
                    .mapNotNull { it.getValue(Goal::class.java) }
                    .sortedBy { it.priority }
                    .toCollection(targetList)
                contract.updateViewContent()
            }

            override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {
                Log.d("some", "Error trying to get targets for ${databaseError.message}")
            }
        }
        targetsRef?.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener)
    }

    fun getTargetsByDeadline() {
        val valueEventListener = object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                targetList.clear()
                dataSnapshot.children
                    .mapNotNull { it.getValue(Goal::class.java) }
                    .sortedBy { it.deadline }
                    .toCollection(targetList)
                contract.updateViewContent()
            }

            override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {
                Log.d("some", "Error trying to get targets for ${databaseError.message}")
            }
        }
        targetsRef?.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener)
    }
}
```

Comment: What would you like to optimize and why do you think that is something wrong in your code that needs optimization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Optimization is the wrong word to describe the issue. The issue is repeating identical code (violating the DRY principle), which can be a problem because it invites error if you need to change something, and it's less readable.

In this case, it's not extreme, but I guess it could be improved somewhat. You can declare a class implementation of the listener that takes a parameter for how to sort the list.

```
class TargetsPresenter(private val contract: SelectTargetViewContract) {

    //...

    fun getTargetsFromDb() {
        targetsRef?.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(MyValueEventListener<String>())
    }

    fun getTargetsByPriority() {
        targetsRef?.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(MyValueEventListener(Goal::priority))
    }

    fun getTargetsByDeadline() {
        targetsRef?.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(MyValueEventListener(Goal::deadline))
    }

    private inner class MyValueEventListener<R: Comparable<R>>(
        private val sortCriteria: (Goal) -> R? = { null }
    ) : ValueEventListener {
        override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            targetList.clear()
            dataSnapshot.children
                .mapNotNull { it.getValue(Goal::class.java) }
                .sortedBy(sortCriteria)
                .toCollection(targetList)
            contract.updateViewContent()
        }

        override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {
            Log.d("some", "Error trying to get targets for ${databaseError.message}")
        }
    }
}
```